# CodeIgniter unable to do segment-based approach

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

All the files are running in localhost, and I am using XAMPP, but I am able to access the content in segment based approach.

for example   http:// localhost/auth/login

In config, i have

```
 <?php
 $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/';
 $config['default_controller'] = 'main'; // Default controller to load
 $config['error_controller'] = 'error'; // Controller used for errors (e.g. 404, 500 etc)
 ?>
```

In controller, i have

```
<?php

class Auth extends Controller {

function index()
{
    // This is the default function (i.e. no function is set in the URL)
}
function login()
{
    echo 'Hello World!';
}
}
?>
```

so when i run it, it should echo "hello world" however, it says object not found!The requested URL was not found on this server. Is that because localhost does not support segment-based approach?

Comment: is the codeigniter installation at the root of your localhost htdocs?

Comment: yes it is, i have installed in local

Comment: at the root of htdocs?

Comment: I dont have a .htaccess file, is that a problem?

Comment: You need to extend CI_Controller unless you're using a very old version of codeigniter, or you've created a core controller that's named 'Controller'

Answer (score 2):

You have not menation `index.php` file in your
 `url is http:// localhost/auth/login but it must be http://localhost/project_name/index.php/controller_name`

You don't need to specify the `base_url` just leave it

```
<?php
 $config['base_url'] = '';
$config['default_controller'] = 'main'; // Default controller to load
$config['error_controller'] = 'error'; // Controller used for errors (e.g. 404, 500 etc)
 ?>
```

and now open `http://localhost/project_name` and it will go to your `default_controller`..

if you want to remove `index.php` than you have to write `.htaccess` rules

Answer (score 1):

In future, please work on projects under subfolder (e.g : `http://localhost/projectA/`)

you need to set up .htacces file (overwrite the xampp one)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```